# Mocking scope function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, scope, apply, mockk

I am using following object creation methods in kotlin

```
class Resource(
               referenceFactory: ReferenceFactory,
               id: String,
               name: String,
               role: String,
               odi_runs: int,
               odi_wickets: int,
               test_runs: int,
               test_wickets: int){
    referenceFactory.calculateRank(Player().apply {
               id = id
               name = name
               role = role
               odi_runs = odi_runs
               odi_wicket = odi_wickets
               test_runs = test_runs
               test_wicket = test_wicket
            })
}
```

then I use this created object for calculate the rank of the player. To get the valid test result from reference factory, I need to mock this 'Player' object creating scope method.

Comment: But in this case `Player` instance is always the same, so can't you just rely on its contents?

Comment: @CommanderTvis, I have edited my question accordingly.